# ACM Certificate not working for sub domain of sub domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb

```
I have one ELB with www.example.com
and another with dev.example.com

I have created separate certificates for both including wildcards and www in Certificate Manager.
Both certificates are verified and issued.

But SSL on www.dev.example.com is not working.

When I check the certificate in Mozilla/Chrome it shows the alt DNS to be example.com, www.example.com, and *.example.com but that's a different certificate which I have not assigned to the listener of ELB of dev.example.com

Any help to make it work?
```

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards only work at one level. You would need to add `*.dev.example.com` to the certificate in order for it to work with `www.dev.example.com`.

Comment: I have added it. the certificate has domains www.dev.example.com , *.dev.example.com, dev.example.com

Comment: I think you need to verify you have the correct certificate assigned to the load balancer.